# Page margins in .Rtex

Tags: graphics, geometry, paper-size, knitr

I'm using ShareLatex to write my thesis (which relies heavily on R) but the page size changes when I set my document to "main.Rtex" instead of "main.tex". I provide a minimal example so you can check it out for yourself. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[vcentering,dvips,hcentering]{geometry}
\geometry{papersize={168mm,225mm},total={124mm,185mm}}
\usepackage{graphicx, subfigure}
\title{Rtex problem}
\author{Guy in need}
\date{October 2015}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this have anything to do with `graphics`? Does the problem disappear if you do not load `graphicx` or `subfigure`? If so, there's an easy solution: you shouldn't be loading `subfigure` anyway as it is obsolete. If not, this stuff doesn't belong in your MWE. I know nothing about R. Could you explain why you need to change the extension exactly?

Comment: Actually, the problem appears if I don't load `graphicx`, even if the file ends in ".tex". This problem definetely has something to to with those. I need to change the extension in order to use `knitr` ([https://es.sharelatex.com/learn/Knitr]) to show and run R code.

Comment: Delete the bits the problem has nothing to do with from the code in your example.

Comment: Are you sure that ShareLaTeX doesn't expect `.Rtex` files to contain *just the code for the figure*? That would explain the change in page size: does it look as if it is cropping the page to 'just fit' the content?